# Is it possible to install a windows service that requires a password with SCCM?

Tags: windows, deployment, windows-service, sccm

Is it possible to do an unattended installed of a windows service that requires a password with SCCM?

It would be nice if SCCM could run a package as a service account. That way the package could read the password from a file encrypted with that service account

Unfortuanly SCCM runs packages as "Local System".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter the account you install the service in.

You can create a batch file to install the service and use the sc.exe command to install the service.